# Good language to Create GUI application with 3D models

Tags: 3d

I am looking into making a application based around accessible information. I wish to have a 3D model i can interact with without having 6 billion lines of code to tell it not to flip upside down.

This is a project for work and i have tried Java 3D but simply getting it to lock rotation to the zAxis (up down axis) is taking far too long and i haven't even started  working on the actual GUI yet.

Also i need to keep this application as accessible as possible so it can be installed by its self and not need multiple 3rd party software.

Comment: Recommendations are out of scope for StackOverflow answers: but take a look at [three.js](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) and see if it would be an appropriate implementation technology for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JavaFX? According to Oracle:

> The JavaFX 3D graphics APIs provide a general purpose three-dimensional graphics library for the JavaFX platform. You can use 3D geometry, cameras, and lights to create, display, and manipulate objects in 3D space.

-[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/overview-3d.htm#CJAHFAHJ)

Comment: I dont believe there is much support for using 3d models such as .obj files. I use Blender to create all the models and already have them set up with .obj and .mtl but java 3D has issues with the .mtl and other things.

Comment: @user3310078 There are [third party libs](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html) for importing models such as `.obj` files into JavaFX.  [Java3D](https://java3d.java.net) != [JavaFX 3D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm), they are different APIs and toolkits.  I do not know if the third party importers would handle your particular blender created files.